# Pixel data of a 16-bit DICOM image to BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, tiff

I've got a byte array storing 16-bit pixel data from an already-deconstructed DICOM file. What I need to do now is convert/export that pixel data somehow into a TIFF file format. I'm using the imageio-tiff-3.3.2.jar plugin to handle the tiff conversion/header data. But now I need to pack that image data array into a BufferedImage of the original image dimensions so it can be exported to TIFF. But it seems that BufferedImage doesn't support 16-bit images. Is there a way around this problem, such as an external library? Is there another way I can pack that image data into a TIFF image of the original DICOM dimensions? Keep in mind, this process has to be completely lossless. I've looked around and tried out some things for the last few days, but so far nothing has worked for me.

Let me know if you have any questions or if there's anything I can do to clear up any confusion.

EDIT: Intended and Current image
[image]

Comment: `BufferedImage` supports many different variations of 16 bit/sample images, even if there's no `TYPE_*` constant except gray data (`TYPE_USHORT_GRAY`). How many channels is your data? Is it gray? RGB? Other? What are the dimensions (w * h)?

Comment: ...and what is the length of your array? Is it really a `byte` array with 16 bit values? Or a `short` array? Is the data supposed to be treated as signed or unsigned values?

Comment: @haraldK I'm using a grayscale unsigned 16-bit image. The width x height is 1760 x 2140. The byte[] is length 7532800. It contains 16-bit balues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your input data of a raw byte array, containing unsigned 16 bit image data, here's two ways to create a `BufferedImage`.

The first one will be slower, as it involves copying the `byte` array into a `short` array. It will also need twice the amount of memory. The upside is that it creates a standard `TYPE_USHORT_GRAY` `BufferedImage`, which may be faster to display and may be more compatible.

```
private static BufferedImage createCopyUsingByteBuffer(int w, int h, byte[] rawBytes) {
    short[] rawShorts = new short[rawBytes.length / 2];

    ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBytes)
            // .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) // Depending on the data's endianness
            .asShortBuffer()
            .get(rawShorts);

    DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferUShort(rawShorts, rawShorts.length);
    int stride = 1;
    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(dataBuffer, w, h, w * stride, stride, new int[] {0}, null);
    ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);

    return new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
}
```

A variant that is much faster (previous version takes 4-5x more time) to create, but results in a `TYPE_CUSTOM` image, that might be slower to display (it does seem to perform reasonable though, in my tests). It's much faster, and uses very little extra memory, as it does no copying/conversion of the input data at creation time.

Instead, it uses a custom sample model, that has `DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT` as transfer type, but uses `DataBufferByte` as data buffer.

```
private static BufferedImage createNoCopy(int w, int h, byte[] rawBytes) {
    DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferByte(rawBytes, rawBytes.length);

    int stride = 2;
    SampleModel sampleModel = new MyComponentSampleModel(w, h, stride);
    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, dataBuffer, null);

    ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);

    return new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
}

private static class MyComponentSampleModel extends ComponentSampleModel {
    public MyComponentSampleModel(int w, int h, int stride) {
        super(DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT, w, h, stride, w * stride, new int[] {0});
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDataElements(int x, int y, Object obj, DataBuffer data) {
        if ((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x >= width) || (y >= height)) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Coordinate out of bounds!");
        }

        // Simplified, as we only support TYPE_USHORT
        int numDataElems = getNumDataElements();
        int pixelOffset = y * scanlineStride + x * pixelStride;

        short[] sdata;

        if (obj == null) {
            sdata = new short[numDataElems];
        }
        else {
            sdata = (short[]) obj;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numDataElems; i++) {
            sdata[i] = (short) (data.getElem(0, pixelOffset) << 8 | data.getElem(0, pixelOffset + 1));
            // If little endian, swap the element order, like this:
//            sdata[i] = (short) (data.getElem(0, pixelOffset + 1) << 8 | data.getElem(0, pixelOffset));
        }

        return sdata;
    }
}
```

If your image looks strange after this conversion, try flipping the endianness, as commented in the code.

And finally, some code to exercise the above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int w = 1760;
    int h = 2140;

    byte[] rawBytes = new byte[w * h * 2]; // This will be your input array, 7532800 bytes

    ShortBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBytes)
//            .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) // Try swapping the byte order to see sharp edges
            .asShortBuffer();

    // Let's make a simple gradient, from black UL to white BR
    int max = 65535; // Unsigned short max value
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        double v = max * y / (double) h;

        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            buffer.put((short) Math.round((v + max * x / (double) w) / 2.0));
        }
    }

    final BufferedImage image = createNoCopy(w, h, rawBytes);
//    final BufferedImage image = createCopyUsingByteBuffer(w, h, rawBytes);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.add(new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image))));

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's what the output should look like (scaled down to 1/10th):

[image]

Comment: That worked brilliantly. Thank you so much! I'm, like, 1000% excited right now because of how many issues this code fixed on two of my projects.

Comment: Actually, the image does look a little odd. It looks like the light and dark channels are switched. Could you clarify with code what you mean by flipping the endianness? I tried what I thought you meant, but it gives me the same result. Thank you!

Comment: @Sarah Which version of the code do you use? If you use the first, you will flip the byte order simply by uncommenting the line `order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`. For the second, you need to swap `pixelOffset` and `pixelOffset + 1`.

Comment: The second code. I tried swapping and get the same result. I'll edit my question in just a moment to show you as snippet of how the image looks and how it's intended to look. Let me know what you think. Besides the seeming inversion, the image is correct (correct dimensions, size, etc).

Comment: There's something strange with your input data, other than byte order. If the byte order was wrong, the image would be very noisy. Instead, it seems that the values are out of range, and wraps, to make a sharp edge at 50% intensity. I'll try to make some updates to my code, to make it easier to understand how input values correspond to output.

Comment: Hmm, now this is interesting. In the second code example, the overriden version of "getDataElements" is never being called. Perhaps THAT is why switching the endians didn't affect the outcome?

Comment: @Sarah: That is very strange... It does in my tests (both Windows & Mac).  It would be interesting to see how the other version of the code looks though...

Comment: The only think I changed in that code example was class/method names, and I added the data array and dimensions as parameters instead of being fixed. But other than that, it should be identical. This is one of those fun little "why, Java?" problems.

Comment: Hmm. It's working in the new example you gave me. I'll do some digging. See what's going on in the main project code.

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far. I got the function working this morning. I have only one question. After flipping the endians, it seems my histogram is still inverted for the image. In code/array structure, how is this reflected and how can I fix it? I've provided an updated image to show you what I mean. Thank you!

Comment: You know what? Neeeevermind! Turns out there isn't a problem with your/my code, it's a problem with the sample image. My colleague, who's doing a similar project in matlab, is having the exact same problem with this specific image. So with that in mind, this question is closed. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Sarah Yes, it looks correct now, other than that the values are inverted compared to the expected image. Might be that the values are stored that way (similar to TIFF PhotometricInterpretation `MinIsWhite` aka `WhiteIsZero`). To display the values correctly, you can just invert the values. But you need some external flag to tell if the values are to be inverted, as you can't see this from the data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to create a BufferedImage of type TYPE_USHORT_GRAY, which is type to use for 16 bits encoding.

```
public BufferedImage Convert(short[] array, final int width, final int height)
    {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY) ;
    short[] sb = ((DataBufferUShort) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, sb, 0, array.length) ;
    return image ;
    }
```

Then you can use Java.imageio to save your image as a TIFF or a PNG. I think that the Twelve Monkey Project allows a better TIFF support for imageio, but you have to check first.

[EDIT] In your case because you deal with huge DICOM images that cannot be stored into a regular BufferedImage, you have to create your own type using the Unsafe class to allocated the DataBuffer.

1. Create a new class DataBufferLongShort that will allocate the needed array/DataBuffer using the Unsafe class. Then you can use Long indexes instead of Integer
2. Create a new class DataBuffer that extends the classical DataBuffer in order to add a type TYPE_LONG_USHORT
   Then you can create the ColorModel with the new DataBuffer.

Comment: I've tried using that method before, but the image data isn't large enough. With the correct width and height, the Raster buffer seems to be 50% too small for my total pixel data. I'll investigate this further, but in the meantime do you have any preliminary thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately you are facing the limitation of BufferedImage :-(. The only solution would be to create a TYPE_CUSTOM image where you create your own DataBuffer using the class UnSafe. In order to simplify such creation, you can use the package JLargeArrays associated with the library JTransform. You have to do that because the DataBuffer length is likely greater than the maximum Integer value.

Comment: Do you have any example code for how to do just that? I've been trying to make my own custom ColorModel with 16-bit pixel depth, but I'm still having trouble getting the whole shebang to work.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I've unfortunately not done that before, but it's how I would do it according to what I see in the code.